# Skip declared tokens at some locations in javacc

Tags: lexical-analysis, javacc

I declared a token `<VOTE>`. I want to use this token to match inside a block delimited by braces. If it comes outside of block, I want to skip it. Currently the token is matched the same regardless of whether it is inside a block or outside and this makes parsing the stuff outside the block a problem.

```
  TOKEN: { < VOTE: " vote" > }

  TOKEN: { < #STRING_LITERAL: ["a" - "z", "A" - "Z", "0" - "9", ".", "_", "-", "!","`", "*", "@", "#", "$", "%", ":", "[", "]", "\"", "^", ";", "\\", "<", ">", "/", ",", "?", "=", "&","(",")","+","|"] >}

  TOKEN: { < DATA: < STRING_LITERAL > ( < STRING_LITERAL > ) * >
    | < OPEN_BRACE: "{" >
    | < CLOSE_BRACE: "}" >}

   **Production:**

   void test():{}
   {
      (<OPEN_BRACE>
          <VOTE>{System.out.println("Voted");}
          <CLOSE_BRACE>)
      |
      <DATA>{System.out.println("Skipped"+token.image);}
   }
```

The above production works for the block

```
hi i am { vote }
```

But it throws an exception for following block

```
hi i vote am { vote }
```

because "vote" is outside the braces. Please show me how to skip "vote" outside braces.

I could mention `<VOTE>` in the production like this

```
   void test():{}
   {
      (<OPEN_BRACE>
          <VOTE>{System.out.println("VOted");}
          <CLOSE_BRACE>)
      |
      (<DATA>|<VOTE>){System.out.println("Skipped"+token.image);}
   }
```

But I don't want to do this because I have lot of tokens, so when I apply this fix in the full scale system it would be hard to maintain.

Comment: I don't know javacc but your description seems self contradicting. Your DATA contains VOTE token, but you don't want to write OR condition for VOTE token in DATA?

Comment: I think this 'match' like operation usually handled by the parser logic (custom routine).

Comment: if you don know javacc don comment please..!

Comment: Sorry, if I bothered you. I just want to mention some contradiction in your lexer/parser definition ;-)

Comment: I didn't imagine that javacc has this level of functionalities. I apologize for my previous comments @BlackPop :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to use are lexical states.  This is covered in the FAQ and the documentation, the relevant parts of which you should read.

Basically what you want to do is something like this

```
<DEFAULT> TOKEN:{
        < #STRING_LITERAL: ["a" - "z", "A" - "Z", "0" - "9", ".", "_", "-", "!","`", "*", "@", "#", "$", "%", ":", "[", "]", "\"", "^", ";", "\\", "<", ">", "/", ",", "?", "=", "&","(",")","+","|"] >
    |   < DATA: < STRING_LITERAL > ( < STRING_LITERAL > ) * > }

<DEFAULT, INBRACES> TOKEN : {
        < OPEN_BRACE: "{" > : INBRACES
    |   < CLOSE_BRACE: "}" > : DEFAULT }

<INBRACES> TOKEN: {
        < VOTE: "vote" > }

<DEFAULT, INBRACES> SKIP { " " | "\r" | "\n" }
```

Now between braces, "vote" will be a VOTE, but outside, it will be a DATA.  Braces and spaces are treated the same regardless of where they are.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. Works like charm +1..If you know any tutorial for javacc pls help me..Thanks again..!

Comment: There is a list of tutorials in the FAQ.

Comment: Is this you saying about??  http://www.engr.mun.ca/~theo/JavaCC-FAQ/javacc-faq-moz.htm..Please provide links..

Comment: Yep. http://www.engr.mun.ca/~theo/JavaCC-FAQ/ is the FAQ.  Although it's a bit out of date, people still say they find it useful.